# How do I query between two dates using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-09-29 10:15:55' AND '2010-01-30 14:15:55')
```

returns nothing.

I should have more than enough data to for the query to work though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be cautious with BETWEEN, as both `min` and `max` values are considered to be in the range, to not process twice a date that is either the `min` and `max` value (edge case). For instance, the date `2010-09-29 00:00:00` will be _between `2010-09-28 00:00:00` and `2010-09-29 00:00:00`_, **AND ALSO** _between `2010-09-29 00:00:00` and `2010-09-30 00:00:00`_

Comment: yea, what he said ^^

Answer (score 626, accepted):

Your second date is before your first date (ie. you are querying between September 29 2010 and January 30 2010). Try reversing the order of the dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Official Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: I did know  this but now has issue with UPDATE. I m trying to use BETWEEN for UPDATE should it work the same way?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: a `where` clause should work the same on `select` or `update` statements.

Comment: Personally, I find the term 'from' and 'to' a sneaky way to remember the order in which the query should be written.

Comment: How to return all data if both dates are null or empty?

Comment: @Codingworld Just drop the WHERE Clause

Answer (score 35):

Your query should have date as

```
select * from table between `lowerdate` and `upperdate`
```

try

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
WHERE  (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Answer (score 34):

DATE() is a MySQL function that extracts only the date part of a date or date/time expression

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(date_field) BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-10';
```

Comment: you *could* add an explanation so people will understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 27):

Is `date_field` of type `datetime`?  Also you need to put the eariler date first.

It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
WHERE  (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Answer (score 22):

As extension to the answer from @sabin and a hint if one wants to compare the *date* part only (without the time):

If the field to compare is from type *datetime* and only *dates* are specified for comparison, then these *dates* are internally converted to *datetime* values. This means that the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE (date_time_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30' AND '2010-09-29')
```

will be converted to

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE (date_time_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 00:00:00' AND '2010-09-29 00:00:00')
```

internally.

**This in turn leads to a result that does not include the objects from 2010-09-29 with a time value greater than 00:00:00!**

Thus, if all objects with date 2010-09-29 should be included too, the field to compare has to be converted to a date:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE (DATE(date_time_field) BETWEEN '2010-01-30' AND '2010-09-29')
```

Comment: Thanks this was useful today.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it manually, by comparing with greater than or equal and less than or equal.

```
 select * from table_name where created_at_column  >=   lower_date  and  created_at_column <= upper_date;
```

In our example, we need to retrieve data from a particular day to day. 
We will compare from the beginning of the day to the latest second in another day.

```
  select * from table_name where created_at_column  >=   '2018-09-01 00:00:00'  and  created_at_column <= '2018-09-05 23:59:59';
```

Comment: This is the best option because A)Simplicity B)Readability

Comment: the comparison between the beginning and end of the day was important in my case

Answer (score 4):

Just Cast date_field as date

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
WHERE (cast(date_field as date) BETWEEN '2010-09-29' AND 
'2010-01-30' )
```

Comment: Awesome, spend almost 2 hours searching and trying and nothing worked out but your amazing solution, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

I just tested on mariaDB with 2 cases as follows:

```
Case 1: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(date_field) BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-10' // include 2016-12-10
Case 2: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-10') // not include 2016-12-10
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Date **and** Time values, you must cast the fields as `DateTime` and not `Date`.
Try :

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
WHERE (CAST(date_field AS DATETIME) 
BETWEEN CAST('2010-09-29 10:15:55' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2010-01-30 14:15:55' AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a problem with date configuration on server side or on client side.
I've found this to be a common problem on multiple databases when the host is configured in spanish, french or whatever... that could affect the format dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: The problem was the older date was listed before the newer date.

Answer (score -1):

Try switching the dates around:

```
2010-09-29 > 2010-01-30?
```

Answer (score -1):

To display post(s) between 2 specific dates (for example):

an occasion starts on (04-12) and ends on (04-14) without selecting a year in query to make it recurrent every year on the specified dates, So my goal is to display that occasion on startdate and hide it automatically on enddate as follow:

```php
$stmt = $db->query(
    "SELECT * FROM table

    WHERE (CAST(CURDATE() AS date)

    BETWEEN

    CAST(table.date_start AS date)
    AND
    CAST(table.date_end AS date))

    LIMIT 1"
);
```

Now, the occasion starts and disappear between these specified dates only, not after or before.