# SQL Server : JOIN and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a new table based on particular values that match between two tables and that works fine but my issue comes about when I try to filter the newly joined table by dates.

```
CREATE TABLE JoinedValuesTable
(
     [Ref] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     [Parties] CHAR(50),
     [Accounts] CHAR(50),
     [Amount] FLOAT
);
```

The table above is created okay and I join insert values into it by joining two tables like this....

```
INSERT INTO JoinedValuesTable ([Parties], [Accounts], [Amount])
    SELECT 
        InputPerson.[PARTY], Input_Y.[R_Account_1], InputPerson.[Amount] 
    FROM 
        InputPerson
    JOIN 
        Input_Y ON InputPerson.[Action] = Input_Y.[Action]
```

And this works fine it's when I try to filter by dates that it doesn't seem to work....

```
INSERT INTO JoinedValuesTable([Parties], [Accounts], [Amount])
    SELECT 
        InputPerson.[PARTY], Input_Y.[R_Account_1], InputPerson.[Amount] 
    FROM 
        InputPerson
    JOIN 
        Input_Y ON InputPerson.[Action] = Input_Y.[Action]
    WHERE 
        InputPerson.[Date] BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-03'
```

I'm not getting any values into my new table. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of `InputPerson.[Date]` ?

Comment: There is no chance that either of those queries work as posted. You have three columns listed in the insert statement and 4 columns of data.

Comment: Does the SELECT standalone return the expected result?

Comment: InputPerson.[Date] is the data of type Date Andrew!

Ah thanks for spotting that Sean! I just fixed it, got any ideas?

The SELECT works as expected and it all does apart from when I include the line that's the where data filter Jarlh

Comment: Yes I have an idea....it is the same idea that @Andrew has. What is the datatype of your Date column?

Comment: It is of type date

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest not to use `CHAR(n)` with such big numbers - `CHAR` is **padded to the defined length** with spaces, e.g. it will always occupy 50 characters (bytes) of space - even if you store only `ABC` in it. I'd recommend using `VARCHAR(50)` instead. Also: be careful with `FLOAT` since it's notoriously prone to rounding errors - I'd recommend using `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead which doesn't have these problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion marc_s!

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `between` for dates.  A better method is:

```
WHERE InputPerson.[Date] >= '2018-01-01' AND
      InputPerson.[Date] < '2018-03-04'
```

I strongly recommend Aaron Bertrand's blog on this topic:  *[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)*

This assumes that `Date` is being stored as a date/time column.  If it is a string, then you need to convert it to a date using the appropriate conversion function.

Comment: ... where the second date is + one day.

Comment: Thank you for the advise and link on how BETWEEN is the devil XDDD but unfortunately it hasn't fixed the issue I'm having :( . Any ideas?

Comment: @OverFlowMars . . . Presumably you have no rows that meet that condition.

Answer (score 0):

A shameless copy/paste from an earlier answer:

```
BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'2018-01-01') AND CONVERT(datetime,'2018-03-03')
```

The original answer: [Datetime BETWEEN statement not working in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451767/datetime-between-statement-not-working-in-sql-server)

I suspect that the datetime versus string is the culprit. Resulting in (without the insert into):

```
SELECT InputPerson.[PARTY], Input_Y.[R_1], Input_Y.[R_Account_1], InputPerson.[Amount] 
FROM InputPerson
JOIN Input_Y ON InputPerson.[Action] = Input_Y.[Action]
WHERE InputPerson.[Date] BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'2018-01-01') AND CONVERT(datetime,'2018-03-03')
```

-- Edit (after comments from Olivier) --

Are you sure the select-statement returns results? Perhaps the Inner-Join combined with the Where-clause results in an empty result set.

Comment: You can use strings as date/time constants in SQL-Server. No need to convert.

Comment: See: "Example - With Date" in [SQL Server: BETWEEN Condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/between.php) (TechNet).

Comment: It appears you are right (just tested it on a test database). Not sure what the problem is. The between statement works with and without the convert. I start to suspect the the select statement is lacking records.

Comment: Yes it works with or without. But does anyone know why I can't use the WHERE to filter between dates to get the desired INSERT?