# php mysql find records between two dates

Tags: mysql

i am working on a system that manages atm card stocks at a local bank. would like code that can parse through the db and give me number of cards received by the branch from the card producers and the number collected by the customers on each day between two specified dates.
Fields in my db AccountNUm,DateReceived,DateCollected

Comment: Example data and expected output please.

Comment: output desired DATE RECEIVED COLLECTED BALANCE

Comment: Please add example data and exptected example output to your question, not just column names

Answer (score 0):

Connection to DB http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm

Difference date [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/mysql-query-between-two-dates)

Use google =\ Question should be really closed.