# MySQL - how to show all date from given range date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, range

I have records like this:

```
id | name | date
1  | aji  | 2014-06-01
2  | akon | 2014-06-02
3  | dewi | 2014-06-04
4  | dani | 2014-06-05
```

I want to display all dates from 2014-06-01 - 2014-06-06, even if they have no records associated:

```
id   | name | date
1    | aji  | 2014-06-01
2    | akon | 2014-06-02
NULL | NULL | 2014-06-03
3    | dewi | 2014-06-04
4    | dani | 2014-06-05
NULL | NULL | 2014-06-06
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: query between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/mysql-query-between-two-dates)

Comment: @user986959, i need to display record eventhough record in that date is empty

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can use this way.

**SQL Server**

```
Select IsNull(id, Null), IsNull(name,Null),date 
   where date Between  2014-06-01 and 2014-06-06.
```

If ID has set to int, then do like this

```
Select IsNull(id, 0), IsNull(name,Null),date 
   where date Between  2014-06-01 and 2014-06-06.
```

**MY SQL**

```
select id, name,date from tr_kehadiran 
    where date >= "2014-06-30" AND date <= "2014-07-06" AND id is Null AND name is Null
```

Please let me know the result.

Comment: Query: select IsNull(id, 0), IsNull(name,0),date from tr_kehadiran where date >= "2014-06-30" AND date <= "2014-07-06" 
Error Code: 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IsNull'

Comment: it display records without 2014-06-03 and 2014-06-06

Comment: Check it now. It's my mistake. Now I changed the IfNull syntax please have a look on my answer part.

Comment: Try it now. I have changed the query. Hope it may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand what you're asking for.
But

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN  '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-06'
```

And

```
<?php
$start = new DateTime('2014-06-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$end = new DateTime('2014-06-06');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date)
{
    if (isset($results['date'][$date]))
    {
        // Results display
    }
    else
    {
        // NULL display
    }
}
```

where $results is the result of your query

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to be followed -

If SQL Server

1. Using CTE, populate a range of date needed as per your requirement
2. Left join your table against the CTE on the date column and populate the dates missing in your result set from CTE

If MySQL -

1. Create a temporary table to populate the date range as per the requirement
2. Left join the temporary table on the date column and populate the dates missing in your result set from CTE