# WHERE date BETWEEN not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count logins by date range by counting how many times the auto integer (id) appears between a start and end date.

I get the start date and end date from a form in a previous page (y-m-d).

```
$start_date=$_POST['start_date']; /*in this case its "2014-10-10"*/
$end_date=$_POST['end_date']; /*in this case its "2014-10-20"*/


$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as login_count FROM `usage`  
GROUP BY id   
WHERE date
BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
SQL;
```

However I keep getting the following syntax error

"There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE date BETWEEN 2014-10-10 AND 2014-10-20' at line 3]"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you quote date strings, it looks like straight arithmetic, 2014 minus 10 minus 10 which gives 1994

Comment: use brackets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

Comment: brackets are NOT necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try it 

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as login_count FROM `usage`  
WHERE date
BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
GROUP BY id   
SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

your $sql should be :

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as login_count FROM `usage`  
WHERE date
BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
GROUP BY id   
SQL;
```

as `GROUP BY CLAUSE` is `AFTER WHERE` syntactically

Comment: Should also quote the date values

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `''`s around date literals in sql like so:

```
$response = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db`.`$sql_table` WHERE (date BETWEEN '$end_date' AND '$start_date')  ORDER by id ASC ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: this does answer the question (apparently correctly), but it is more useful to to add a brief explanation of your answer. Just something like "You need to put quotes around date literals" would be enough.

Comment: @Rhumborl, got it thanks. will do on my next answers. just new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should quote your dates '$start_date' AND '$end_date' and you should definitely make sure those values are escaped to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Fair do's but no one has pointed out about SQL injection as this code would be very vulnerable?

Comment: Sure, but this should go into a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in your SQL. Try this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as login_count FROM `usage`  
WHERE (date BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date)
GROUP BY id;
```