# mysql select between two date ranges using BETWEEN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select between two date ranges and my query doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my query... what have i done wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order` WHERE created_at Between '2015-03-17 18:33:45' AND '2015-02-12 22:18:41'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between is from lower to higher you have higher to lower

```
 Between '2015-03-17 18:33:45' AND '2015-02-12 22:18:41'
```

should be

```
 Between '2015-02-12 22:18:41' AND '2015-03-17 18:33:45'
```