# mysql query function - date range

Tags: mysql, date, range

here's my data structure:

```
seasons
id  from         to           name
-----------------------------------------
1   2015-11-01   2015-12-15   season1
2   2015-12-16   2015-12-30   season2
3   2015-12-31   2016-01-20   season3
```

i need a sql query which will return all records between date range `2015-12-10` and `2015-12-20` - which would be record 1 and 2.
any ideas?

Comment: Look up how BETWEEN works.  It's pretty much "where date is between thisdate and thatdate"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: but isn't the BETWEEN operator just for one date .. i want to compare one range with another range

Comment: It seems you are looking after *overlapping* interval detection. `BETWEEN` operator will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

best explanation for date overlap [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE `from` <= '2015-12-20'
  AND `to` >= '2015-12-10'
```

Please not use reserved words like `from` as field names

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `BETWEEN` operator.

Like here:
[How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Edit:

According to your data structure, you could use > and < operators.

```
SELECT * FROM `seasons` 
WHERE from > '2015-12-10' AND to < '2015-12-20'
```

Comment: This should really be left as a comment.  It's not really an answer.  Or, more specifically, your answer.