# Timestamp gets updated with zero

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I need to update a column with datatype as `timestamp`. I run the following query:

```
update job_info set ProcessStartTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) where JobID=4;
```

But it updates with a value : `0000-00-00 00:00:00` What could be the reason for this? Is the query incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` because MySQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns a Unix timestamp in `seconds` or your column type is `datetime`

```
update job_info set ProcessStartTime =CURDATE() where JobID=4;
```

or use `NOW()`

```
update job_info set ProcessStartTime =NOW() where JobID=4;
```

Comment: When I try to insert timestamp using curdate/now it inserts date-string. Why is that? How will I run a query that returns data for timestamp values between `1448994600` and alike?

Comment: if your column type is datetime there is no issues @SuhailGupta

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

Comment: check this link for more details @SuhailGupta