# How to find list of people whose age is between a range?

Tags: mysql

I have this situation where I have date-of-birth stored in database eg. 1990/03/15. I want to find out info. of records whose age is between 20 & 30. How should I write this query?

I have tried this:
I get age of all candidates using this query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) as age FROM `profile`
```

How to use it to get list of all candidates between age 20 & 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NOW()` gives the current Date. Now, to get date 20 and 30 years older, we can do the following:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR)
AND 
DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

Now the remaining query is very simple.
That is,

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE dateOfBirth BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR) 
                  AND DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
```

Comment: This works ... 

SELECT * FROM profile WHERE dob BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -20 YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 YEAR)

Comment: FYI.. date 20 gives the date which is 20 years ahead of today.

Comment: I think you need to swap the positions so that the oldest (-30) date is first in the `BETWEEN` statement.

Comment: According to this question it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql