# Comparing my user date checkin and checkout input to find apartment availability [php,mysql]

Tags: php, mysql

Hi id like to search for available apartments within a specific date (user specified)

MySQL system_apartment table:

[image: system_apartment]

MySQL system_booking table:

[image: system_booking]

This is the current code for my php process

```
if($_POST)
{
$user_checkin    = test_input($_POST['checkin']);
$user_checkout   = test_input($_POST['checkout']);
$user_noofpeople = test_input($_POST['noofpeople']);
$user_roomtype   = test_input($_POST['roomtype']);


try
{
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("
        SELECT r.* 
          FROM system_apartment AS r 
         WHERE r.apartment_id 
        NOT IN
             (
                SELECT b.booking_apartmentid 
                  FROM system_booking AS b
                 WHERE (b.booking_date_checkout >= $user_checkin AND b.booking_date_checkin <= $user_checkout)
                    OR (b.booking_date_checkout <= $user_checkin  AND b.booking_date_checkin >= $user_checkout)
             )
    ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $count = count($count);

    if($count==0){
        echo "working"; //  not available
    }
    else{
        echo "not working"; //  not available
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I would very much appreciate it if anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong!

Comment: My date is being sent as a (input type="text") is that the reason? or is there a work around if so because i am using jquery validate to make sure the field is being send

Comment: You cannot directly input `php `variables inside of a `mysqli prepared statement`. You must use `bind_param` and the placeholder `?` where you would normally use a variable and then assign it later.

Comment: please consider create a fiddle with the problem, http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: `$user_checkin` and `$user_checkout` are what, integers or strings? Doubting you're checking for errors here.

Comment: What the result are you getting, and what the expected result ? What do you mean by not working if count equals to 0? Would you consider using a join instead?

Comment: Moreover, the second WHERE clause is unneeded unless time can flow along negative direction.

Comment: see the answer below then. Nothing more I can do here, till I know exactly what animal we're dealing with. Good luck

Comment: @Reversal how would you perform the sql statement using a join? It is intending to search the database with the given dates provided by the user to see if there are any available apartments with the specified apartment_type within the given dates. If there are some available then they should be displayed, otherwise if they are unavailable then don't display them.

Comment: `WHERE (b.booking_date_checkout >= :user_checkin AND b.booking_date_checkin <= :user_checkout)` is enough to select every apartment busy in the window `($user_checkin,$user_checkout)`.

Comment: @Reversal Did you miss out the last bit? Where it says ($user_checkin....) is that supposed to be : $stmt->execute(array(':user_checkin'=>$user_checkin, ':user_checkout'=>$user_checkout));

Comment: Yes, I just wrote down WHERE clause. The execution can be done the way you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your SQL is correct for your task, fix this bit of code to:

```
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("
        SELECT r.* 
          FROM system_apartment AS r 
         WHERE r.apartment_id 
        NOT IN
             (
                SELECT b.booking_apartmentid 
                  FROM system_booking AS b
                 WHERE (b.booking_date_checkout >= :user_checkin AND b.booking_date_checkin <= :user_checkout)
                    OR (b.booking_date_checkout <= :user_checkin AND b.booking_date_checkin >= :user_checkout)
             )
    ");

$stmt->bindParam(':user_checkin', $user_checkin);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_checkout', $user_checkout);
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> The SQL statement can contain zero or more named (:name) or question
>   mark (?) parameter markers for which real values will be substituted
>   when the statement is executed. You cannot use both named and question
>   mark parameter markers within the same SQL statement; pick one or the
>   other parameter style. Use these parameters to bind any user-input, do
>   not include the user-input directly in the query.
>
> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to
>   pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You
>   cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in
>   a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

**Sidenote:** the `BETWEEN` operator might be of use to you, [doc page here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: Sure it might be a possible fix, but what about explaining where they might have made errors?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Added a reference to the potential explanation of errors/motivation for the answer

Comment: How would I use the between statement instead? Could you show how the code would look? sorry my brain is fried

Comment: @LukeWilliams You don't have to use it; in fact, it may not even be possible with the logic you have in your query. Just noting it in case it may come in handy, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql) is how it's used.