# PHP/MySQLi Code only listing events in current year and ignoring future years

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got the code listed below.  For some reason it is only listing events of 2016.  The moment I put in an event ending in 2017, it doesn't show it.

Any idea why?

```
    $currentdate = date('m-d-Y');

    $events_call = $eventsdb->query("
SELECT * FROM events WHERE start <= '". $currentdate ."' 
AND (end >= '". $currentdate ."' OR end = 0) ORDER BY end ASC");
```

I am formatting dates in a mm-dd-yyyy format.  Ex: 11-18-2016

Comment: What's the data type of `start` and `end`? If it's `DATE`, their format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and not `MM-DD-YYYY`

Comment: its just a varchar(11) data type.  And the start date is 11-17-2016 and the end date is 01-01-2017

Comment: Don't use `VARCHAR` for dates, the string comparison fails in this case. Use `DATE` or `DATETIME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am formatting dates in a mm-dd-yyyy format. Ex: 11-18-2016

PHP, or MySQL for that matter, doesn't automatically know these are dates, it just interprets them as numerical strings. So 11-17-2016 is greater than 01-01-2017 (11,172,016 vs 01,012,017)... You can change the format to YYYY-MM-DD before doing the comparison to solve the problem, or convert the dates to timestamps, etc...

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly? do you want the results BETWEEN the 2 dates? if so, take a look for the BETWEEN sql command, like:

[How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

But i dont think that you can store date information in mysql in `mm-dd-yyyy` format. Mysql accepts `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Check your table structure please is it in date format?