# Why is my query not working using the BETWEEN operator?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query and get a result based on 2 dates. When using the query below I keep getting this error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN '2017-12-10' AND '2017-12-30')' at line 1

Below is the query I am trying to use. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
SELECT * FROM checkout WHERE id = 10 AND (BETWEEN '2017-12-10' AND '2017-12-30')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

Comment: **What's** between the two dates?

Comment: missing column name before BETWEEN

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the column name for `between`

```
column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 1):

Add a column name before "between"

```
SELECT * FROM checkout WHERE id = 10 AND ( `columnname` BETWEEN '2017-12-10' AND '2017-12-30')
```

This will help you