# Mysql - Incorrect datetime value in where clause with datetime LIKE '2018-01%'

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-like

Can somebody tell me please why this command throws me an error if there is LIKE clasue on datetime? Here is the code:

```
UPDATE surveys
LEFT JOIN tasks ON surveys.task_id = tasks.id
SET surveys.ended = tasks.date_to_resolve
WHERE tasks.date_to_resolve LIKE '2018-01%' AND surveys.ended LIKE '2018-02%'
```

It throws the error "**Incorrect datetime value: '2018-01%' for column 'date_to_resolve' at row 1**"
The strangest thing is the SELECT statement works well with the same condition

```
SELECT * FROM surveys
LEFT JOIN tasks ON surveys.task_id = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.date_to_resolve LIKE '2018-01%' AND surveys.ended LIKE '2018-02%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `like` for dates.  MySQL has very good support for actual date functions.

So:

```
WHERE tasks.date_to_resolve >= '2018-01-01' AND tasks.date_to_resolve < '2018-02-01' AND
      surveys.ended >= '2018-02-01' AND surveys.ended < '2018-03-01'
```

This prevents the implicit conversion between dates and times and allowes the engine to make use of optimizers (if the appropriate ones are available).

EDIT:

The proper `update` query is:

```
UPDATE surveys s JOIN
       tasks t
       ON s.task_id = t.id
    SET s.ended = t.date_to_resolve
    WHERE t.date_to_resolve >= '2018-01-01' AND t.date_to_resolve < '2018-02-01' AND
          s.ended >= '2018-02-01' AND surveys.ended < '2018-03-01';
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is being undone by the `WHERE`, so you might as well express the join correctly.

Comment: Yes this works but it is much longer than LIKE. Thanks. Please correct the question marks in the code.

Comment: using between is a shorter approach if you feel this is to long. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3822648/3664960 and https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

Comment: @Čamo . . .  There are no question marks in this answer.

Comment: Yes it should be - single quotes. Sorry my English is little confused.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon already explained, don't use like for date fields.

Another option would be the use of between

```
WHERE tasks.date_to_resolve between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01' 
  AND surveys.ended between '2018-02-01' AND '2018-03-01'
```

See [between question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822668/3664960) and [techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php)

Comment: It solves the problem but I need to use it with ORM which does not know between clause. Thanks.