# Sort Table via Date Picker Range

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to sort the data table via date picker range (*server side*) but can't get the date sorting part to work properly. Surely there are missing codes and other problems.

What am I missing?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>List</title>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">List</h1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
        <center> <p class="search_input">
        <form method="post" action="#">
        <input type="date" name="dateFrom">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" name="dateTo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="range" id="range" class="btn-info" />
        </form>
        </center>

<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead class="fixedthead">
  <th width="120px" style="text-align: center; color: navy">Name</th>
  <th width="120px" style="text-align: center; color: navy">Description</th>
  <th width="120px" style="text-align: center; color: navy">Date</th>
  <th width="120px" style="text-align: center; color: navy">Open</th>
  </thead>

  <?php 
//retrieve content via data picker range
$dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
$dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];


  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "order");
      // get results from database
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM order.item WHERE date BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo' ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)
  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
  ?>

    <tbody>   
    <tr>     
    <td width="120px" style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td width="120px" style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    <td width="120px" style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
    <td width="120px"><a href = "download.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style='text-decoration:none;'><button>View</button></a></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><br><br><br>
<?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: why is the `while` loop empty?

Comment: First and foremost, you wan to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), your code is **vulnerable**! Second, what are the percent signs doing in that expression, `BETWEEN '$dateFrom%' AND '$dateTo%'`?

Comment: @sticky bit - That actually came from the SQL LIKE Operator that I forgot to take out.

Comment: What's a `LIKE` doing on a date? They aren't stored as `varchar`, are they? If they are, change that and use a proper data type like `date`.

Comment: @stickybit - yes, I agree. I was just testing and took it out after.

Comment: don't mix myqli_ and mysql_ functions.  (i see a reference to mysql_error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: You have a database called `order`, with a table called `item`?

Comment: @Strawberry - Hello! Yes, that is correct. I've updated the code above as to where I am now, though it is still not retrieving anything.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about your database...

```
$last_five_days = time() - 432000;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order.item WHERE order.date > ".$last_five_days." ORDER BY order.date ASC";
```

If this answer doesn't help, then you need to provide us with more information about what you mean by "date picker range."

`ORDER BY {column} ASC|DESC` orders the rows by the indicated column.  It defaults to `ASC`.

I'm using the `WHERE` clause to set up your last-five-days requirement.  I'm assuming `order.date` (whatever you've actually named that) is storing a simple UNIX timestamp.

Comment: The `ORDER` clause comes **after** the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @stickybit, Yes it does!  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @JBH - Hi! I've added a screenshot above. The date picker is FROM and TO, it will supposedly sort the content via that specified date range.

Comment: @David, just to be clear, the "last 5 days" issue is irrelevant because the user is supplying both sides of the date range?

Comment: @JBH - Yes, that for a different concept but totally irrelevant in the date range sorting.

Comment: OK!  Please note that how to query between dates has already been answered on the site.  So I've flagged your question as a duplicate.  Follow the link that appears in your question's comment chain to get to the answer.  (This is normal for SO, BTW).  Use the `ORDER BY {} ASC|DESC` clause to sort the list.