# Mysql - check if date is in some range

Tags: mysql

Assume that we have a table like this:

```
(ID, StartDate, EndDate, SubjectID)
(1, '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '1')
(2, '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01', '1')
(n, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-15', '1')
```

For the specified date (for example '2018-04-04'), i want to check if this date is in any of existing ranges for that subject. How to do this in Mysql?
Problem is that number of ranges is variable per subject (we can have 1 to n rows (ranges) per subject).

Comment: `'2018-04-04' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate`

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily get the required output using the "Greater Than Equal To" and the  "Less Than Equal To" filter in mysql.
Simply place the query as

```
Select SubjectID From your_table
Where StartDate <= '2018-04-04' 
AND EndDate >= '2018-04-04';
```

It should do the trick. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubjectID FROM table_name WHERE StartDate < '2018-04-04' 
  AND EndDate > '2018-04-04';
```