# MySQL: Data from specific day group by year

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have two columns "date" and "temperature". I want to select average temperature between two specific dates e.g. 1 - 7 April grouped by year.
When i use this query

```
select avg(temperature) from table where dayofyear(date) between 91 and 97 group by year(date)
```

two problems appear.

1. In leap years dayofyear for days after 28 February has different value
2. When I want select average from e.g. between 30 December and 5 January this query: `select avg(temperature) from table where dayofyear(date) between 364 and 5 group by year(date)` returns 'null'.

In coresponding to point 2 is another problem. How to receive data between e.g. 30 December (a year before) and 5 January grouped by year?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, use the SQL `DAY()` and `MONTH()` functions:

```
SELECT AVG(temperature)
FROM table
WHERE DAY(date) between 1 and 7 AND MONTH(date) = 4
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

For the second part, you may have to split it into two parts.

Comment: That's period was only for example. When period contains two different months your query returns incorrect values.

Comment: Would enclosing the month and day sections in parenthesis and adding multiple of them using the ‘OR’ operator work?

Comment: I take the datas from some variable in my code. So I don't know when period contains one and when two months. I can use some 'IF' operations with your solution but I looking for simpler methods.

Comment: What exact type of data are you getting from your code? Two days of year? Two days of month and months of year?

Comment: Date in format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Modify code to extracting day and month number is no problem for me

Comment: Will this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822668/11354266 Just set the time to something like 00:00:00

Comment: With this solution grouping by year (date) will not working

Comment: You could do `GROUP BY DAY(<your full date>)` for grouping by day or `GROUP BY YEAR(<your full date>)` for grouping by year.

Comment: When you use date which contains any year then grouping by year returns one row with data with year from query...

Comment: Yeah, it may just be easier to modify the code to extract the month and year

Comment: So, what when period contains dates from two different years, for example since 29 December (a year before) to 4 January?

Comment: Good point... hmm... Back to my suggestion 2 comments ago, it would only be grouping into one year since your query is limiting it to a specific year

Comment: Yes, for this reason this is no solution for me. Thanks