# query for available rooms in hotel reservation between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select just the available rooms in hotel reservation system

Here's my query

```
echo $str = $_POST['start'];
echo $en = $_POST['end'];
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM chambre 
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_chambre 
                         FROM reservation_client
                         where start < $en
                            or end >=$str)";
```

But the query gives me the rooms that are not in table `reservation_client` not the rooms available between `$str` and `$en` date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: You are using not in so that will get result not that range date

Comment: @hs-dev2MR i should replace it by IN ?

Comment: Yes also you need to use AND not `or` for date range

Comment: when i do this its not give me any room to select

Comment: @omayamauchiha How about Qirel answer !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead, and see where the reservations are `NULL` (meaning there were no left joins).

```sql
SELECT c.* 
FROM chambre AS c
LEFT JOIN reservation_client AS rc
  ON c.id = rc.id_chambre AND rc.start < '$en' AND rc.end >= '$str'
WHERE rc.id_chambre IS NULL
```

Though you should be using a prepared statement and bind your values through placeholders instead.