# Update Mysql row where date equal to todays date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a row in my table where the date in a column is equal to today's date.

I have today's date in a variable $currentDate and when I echo this out it is displayed on the screen in the following format

2020-05-08

Which looks same format as the Db table, but I still get the error invalid datetime format.

Below is the code I'm using. Any help please

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$currentTemp = 33;

echo $currentDate;

$sql = "UPDATE weather_station SET currentTemp = $currentTemp WHERE date = $currentDate";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: You are using the right method with prepared statements but you still inject raw variables value in your query instead of using parmeters. Please see [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) that explains how to use parameters.

Comment: 2020 minus 5 minus 8 = 2007

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql

Comment: Yes it was parameters, I though I had used this and it was still not working but must made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE weather_station SET currentTemp = :temp WHERE date = :currenDate";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":temp", $currentTemp);
$stmt->bindParam(":currenDate", $currentDate);
$stmt->execute();
```

This works now