# SELECT BETWEEN two dates php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

i have a very simple SQL which driving me crazy.
I am working with Car Rental - so there is a FromDate and a ToDate (booked cars)

My MySQL loos like this:

```
id | FromDate | ToDate
-----------------------
24 | 01.10.2020 | 31.10.2020
```

so if a user choose a Date in between this, he should get a message that the car is already booked. What i have tried so far:

```
SELECT id FROM booked_cars WHERE ($fromdate BETWEEN date(FromDate) AND date(ToDate)) AND vhId = $vhid
SELECT id FROM booked_cars WHERE ($fromdate BETWEEN date(FromDate) AND date(ToDate) AND $todate BETWEEN date(FromDate) AND date(ToDate)) AND vhId = $vhid
SELECT id FROM booked_cars WHERE (date(FromDate) BETWEEN $fromdate AND $todate) AND vhId = $vhid
```

my $fromdate, $todate and $vhid comes with a POST-Form.
The Values are

```
$fromdate = 03.10.2020
$todate = 07.10.2020
$vhid = 24
```

no matter what i try, my $statement->rowCount() is alway zero.

i am using PDO with prepared Statements. i just wrote it without for better reading.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM booked_cars WHERE (:fromdate BETWEEN date(FromDate) AND date(ToDate)) AND vhId = :vhid");
$statement->execute(array('fromdate' => $fromdate, 'vhid' => $vhid));
echo $statement->rowCount(); // Alway 0 with BETWEEN (when i select just the vhid, i got the result)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: no it doesn't. because my second Date isn't before the first @james

Comment: What format  have FromDate & ToDate fields? Is they datetime?

Comment: Try the next one: ```$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `booked_cars` WHERE `id` = {$vhid} AND ('{$fromdate}' BETWEEN `FromDate` AND '{$todate}' OR `FromDate` BETWEEN '{$fromdate}' AND '{$todate}')")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) here, most probably dates kept in database have a `YYYY-mm-dd` format.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `booked_cars` WHERE `vhId` = :vhid AND STR_TO_DATE(:fromdate,'%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN `FromDate` AND `ToDate`;");
```

In case fields `FromDate` and `ToDate` type is `DATETIME`:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `booked_cars` WHERE `vhId` = :vhid AND STR_TO_DATE(:fromdate,'%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN DATE(`FromDate`) AND DATE(`ToDate`);");
```

The above query is similar to the one used in this [DB Fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wRA5nGKGsFxxwVQUnpey5Z/0).

Comment: thank you peter. this way i got a result. BUT i even got a result when i select a date which isn't at the range f.e. 01.11.2020 - 05.11.2020. any suggestions ?

Comment: Before trying to figure out how you should do it in PHP, write the query out manually in a MySQL console and get that working. Then you can figure out how to do it inside of PHP. In this case you are only providing the "fromDate" in your query, you also need to use the "toDate"