# need to check room availability

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel

i passed checkin_date , checkout_date using ajax to controller.  i need to check what rooms free between checkin_date AND checkout_date... what is the wrong of that query?

```
public function available_rooms($checkin_date,$checkout_date ){
       $arooms = DB::SELECT("SELECT * FROM tbl_rooms WHERE room_number NOT IN (SELECT room_number FROM bookings WHERE ('$checkin_date' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date) AND ('$checkout_date' BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date) )");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql)

Comment: no. i need to check to both $checkin_date and $checkout_date. using AND clause. can you see what is the problem of my query,s logic

Comment: Your query logic is incorrect. If queried period contains existing row's period completely then the overlapping won't be detected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the ranges overlapping detection (ranges overlaps when each range start is less than opposite range end).
2. Use WHERE NOT EXISTS, it breaks the searching for a row when first matched occurence found rather than WHERE NOT IN which gathers all matched rows.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM booking
                   WHERE room.room_id = booking.room_id
                     AND booking.checkin_date < $checkout_date
                     AND $checkin_date < booking.checkout_date );
```

Depends on needed logic you may use not strict but soft (`>=` and `<=`) unequiation operators.

The index `booking (room_id, checkin_date, checkout_date)` should improve the query.